# Difference between $P(A\times B)$ and $P(A)\times P(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In set theory, what is the difference between $P(A\times B)$ and $P(A)\times P(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are sets with greater than zero elements each, where $P(X)$ is the power set of $X$?

Comment: What does A*B mean?

Comment: What is $*{}{}$?

Comment: * is multiplication sorry

Comment: Does P(A) mean probability of A or power set of A?

Comment: How do you multiply two sets?

Comment: @bof it is a power set

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $A\times B$?

Comment: Have you tried some simple examples? If you need inspiration, $A = \{ 1 \}$ and $B = \{ 2 \}$. What are $P(A)$, $P(B)$, and $P(A \times B)$?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the definitions of the two sets:

- An element of $\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B)$ is a pair $(U,V)$, where $U \subseteq A$ and $V \subseteq B$.
- An element of $\mathcal{P}(A \times B)$ is a set $W$ of pairs $(a,b)$, where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

There is a natural map $\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B) \to \mathcal{P}(A \times B)$ defined by
$$(U,V) \mapsto \{ (a,b) \in A \times B \mid a \in U,\ b \in V \}$$
But not every element of $\mathcal{P}(A \times B)$ need be of this form.

Answer (score 2):

The two sets don't necessarily have anything to do with each other.  For example, take $A= \{1\}, B = \{1,2\}$.  We then have
$$
P(A \times B) = \{\{\},\{(1,1)\},\{(1,2)\},\{(1,1),(1,2)\}\}\\
P(A) \times P(B) = 
\{(\{\},\{\})
(\{\},\{1\}), (\{\}, \{2\}),(\{\},\{1,2\}),\\
\qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad
(\{1\},\{\})(\{1\},\{1\}), (\{1\}, \{2\}),(\{1\},\{1,2\})\}
$$
Note that $|P(A \times B)| = 2^{|A|\cdot|B|}$, while
$|P(A) \times P(B)| = 2^{|A|}2^{|B|} = 2^{|A|+|B|}$.